# zend framework update problem(update multiple rows)

Tags: database, zend-framework

i want to update multiple rows in DB using Zend Framework(Zend_db).
i want to add 2 to one field of each row
what should i use?
im a beginner to ZF.

Answer (score 1):

```
$row = array('theColumnName' => new Zend_Db_Expr('theColumnName + 2'));
$where = "id > 50"; 
// leave out the $where parameter to update all rows.
$nRowsUpdated = $db->update('tableName', $row, $where);
```

if you have multiple where conditions, you can do this:

```
$where = array();
$where[] = "foo = something";
$where[] = "id > something";
```

You should read the [Zend_Db reference guide](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html), which has plenty of examples.

Comment: $row = array('theColumnName1' => new Zend_Db_Expr('theColumnName1 + 2') , 'theColumnName2' => new Zend_Db_Expr('theColumnName2 + 2'));

$where = "condition1 and condition2"; 


is it right if i use that like this one?